# Abort out of nested function in loop

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C#, and have just "dug in".  I got my first simple utility app that is working well, but I have a problem when it throws an error.

Right now I have two functions, one looped.

```
Main(){Foo(){loop{foo2()
```

Most stuff in foo2 is local to foo2, so if there is a failure, it just returns and works on the next item, no big deal.  But when there is an error that affects everything, I want to basically do a return twice or basically throw up messagebox & stop running current foo2() and enclosing foo().

How do I do that so that foo doesn't keep looping, and thus throwing a messagebox for the error on all the remaining runs of foo2()

Comment: You can simply `return` from the method, after checking for the condition. It is hard to tell how exactly to do it, could you give use more context?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a variable that monitors "failure" and the foo() function checks it and returns if it is set.  Is that the best way of doing it?

It is possible foo2() runs into a condition that will fail for all iterations of the loop, so right now since my messagebox/return is in foo2(), it will show the error dialog box 5-200 times depending on how many times you loop.  I know I can create a flag that I watch when calling foo2 and if it is set, just stop but didn't know if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I think the best soulution will really depend on what the actual methods are and what they do, and what exact type of error you want to allow and disallow. Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: foo() basically just contains a loop calling foo2(), foo2() builds a stringbuilder based on a lot of inputs and logic and then writes it out to a file.  But before writing it out to a file it checks the syntax and makes sure it is correct.  If the syntax fails, it will throw a messagebox and "return" but this puts it back into the loop which will fail again since the inputs have the wrong syntax.  I need foo2() to be able to return before the loop it is called in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is "an error", then maybe throwing (and catching) an exception is an option, i.e.

```
try {
   // lots
     // of 
        // loops
            throw new InvalidOperationException("oops");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

noting that really your UI code (message-box) and the *actual* code are best separated.

Another option is to simply use `return` or `return [some value]` to exit a sub-methods at the point you need, i.e.

```
string message = TryAndDoSomething();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) MessageBox.Show(message);
...
string TryAndDoSomething() {
   // lots
       // of
           // loops
                 return "oops";
    ...
   return null; // all ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your scenario, so let me know if this solves your issue. Forgive the syntax.

```
foo()
    {
      if(error-that-effects-everything)
        {
           return 0;
        }
      else if(error-that-doesn't)
        {
           return 1; 
        }
      else{}
    }

    bar()
    {
       retval = null;
       while(retval != 0)
       {
         retval = foo();
       }

    }

    Main()
    {
      bar();
    }
```